# Is HRTF always on when using OpenAL?

Tags: ios, xcode, openal

I want to have my app process positional audio and make a binaural mix for those wearing headphones. From what I can tell as soon as I position the listener and the audio source, if I'm using OpenAL it will automatically go for HRTF, but I'm not 100% sure. Does it need to be enabled somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean "go for" HRTF? Do you mean apply HRTF filtering to the sound?

Comment: HRTF = Head-Related Transfer Function. It's the algorithm that OpenAL uses to simulate a binaural recording with a dummy head.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Openal or Openal-soft?

If you are using Openal-soft:

Currently (version 1.16), you need to modify ~/.alsoftrc (or /etc/openal/alsoft.conf for it to be global for all users), and add:

[general] hrtf = true